# Harem manga where the main character gets blessed every time he gets dumped

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was one of the first manga I read; I later moved on to the novel to continue reading it.

It was fantasy/harem. The main character confessed to a girl, got dumped and some goddess blessed him. From that point the main character starts a journey and keeps confessing to different girls, keeps getting dumped and new goddess keeps giving him blessings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall anything distinctive about the art or the depiction of any of the characters?  Do you remember any character or place names?

Comment: Hi, i readed this about 5 or 6 years ago,  sadly i cant remember any name or distinctives... i know its few info to work, sory about that.

Comment: Was this a black and white manga or a full color webtoon? Do you remember anything about the blessings, or what the main character did with them?

Comment: Black and white for sure, the blessings were associated to different elements. Also the more he got, there was some kind of stat window and his status of human changed more and more getting the one of a god. I remember he was concerned about loosing humanity. Thank you guys to take the time and patience to answer :)

Comment: Just noting that, in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281012/looking-for-a-manga-lost-after-hitting-last-chapter-i-closed-it-on-manga-websit?noredirect=1&lq=1, they say that https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/sono-mono-nochi-ni-shinichirou-nariie might be an answer to this. I have not had a chance to research this.