# Manga where a guy has a system where he levels up his exes. Winds up with a daughter made from his mana

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

The Manga where the mc progresses with a system picking up girls along the journey only for the system to learn and gain emotions along the way falling in love with the mc and finally leveling up and evolving (leaving him with a first and final kiss) and with a daughter made from his mana and the system to raise with his lover/lovers.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Black and White with beginning of chapters illustrated in color I believe

Comment: Any chance this is the same story as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272588 ? (No answers, but might have additional details)

Comment: No that one sounds like "That person Later on" or "Sono Mono. Nochi Ni... (Shinichirou Nariie)"